# CSS Placement concern

Tags: css, sass

Not really a problem but more of a 'what do you guys do'

Say you have set up a base typography section of your stylesheet with styles for headers and links and so on. so for this example, say headers are all read and links are blue

You then put an h1 and h2 on a page. Now, a client comes along and say they want a link on a specific h2 on a certain page. You want to add the link but visually keep it looking the same.

Do you:

1. Add the a style as a child style of the h2 in the typographic section like h2 a { styles; }
2. Add the h2.this-one a style to a sort of page specific part of your stylesheet.

I know both will work fine but what do you guys do?

Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you foresee this potentially happening in the future... if so use the  `h2 a` method